# Custom customer attribute not save 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, magento2.4.6

I have created customer attribute with custom source model, I am getting below error , the same code is working fine with 2.4.5

I am getting below error while saving in admin

Attribute `attribute_code` does not contain option with Id `value`

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace Vendor\Customer\Setup\Patch\Data;

    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

    class AddCustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
         */
        private $moduleDataSetup;
        /**
         * @var CustomerSetup
         */
        private $customerSetupFactory;
        /**
         * @var SetFactory
         */
        private $attributeSetFactory;

        /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
         * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
         * @param SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        ) {
            $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function apply()
        {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            /** @var $attributeSet Set */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'attribute_code',
                [
                    'label' => 'Some Label',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'source' => \Amici\Company\Model\Config\Source\AttributeCode::class,
                    'required' => false,
                    'position' => 333,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'system' => false,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                    'backend' => ''
                ]
            );

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_code');
            $attribute->addData([
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ]
            ]);
            $attribute->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId

            ]);
            $attribute->save();

            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }

        public function revert()
        {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
            $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_code');

            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getAliases()
        {
            return [];
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public static function getDependencies()
        {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Code of `\Amici\Company\Model\Config\Source\AttributeCode`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Company\Model\Config\Source;

use Vendor\Company\Model\RegionsFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class AttributeCode extends Table implements ArrayInterface
{
    private RegionsFactory $regionsFactory;
    private ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * 
     * @param CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param RegionsFactory $regionsFactory
     * @param OptionFactory $attrOptionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        RegionsFactory $regionsFactory,
        OptionFactory $attrOptionFactory
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->regionsFactory = $regionsFactory;
        parent::__construct($attrOptionCollectionFactory, $attrOptionFactory);
    }
    /**
     * @return []
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $regionLevel3ollection = $this->regionsFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('level',3);
        $config = [];
        foreach ($regionLevel3ollection as $item) {
            $config[] = [
                'label'     => $item->getLabel(),
                'parent_id' => $item->getParent(),
                'value'     => $item->getId()
            ];
        }
        return $config;
    }

    public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
    {
       return $this->toOptionArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code of this class : Amici\Company\Model\Config\Source\AttributeCode

Comment: @DhirenVasoya please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in  `\Amici\Company\Model\Config\Source\AttributeCode` add `getSpecificOptions` method with below code

```
public function getSpecificOptions($ids, $withEmpty = true)
{
    $regionLevel2Collection = $this->regionsFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('level', 2)
            ->addFieldToFilter('code', ['in' => $ids]); // your collection with $value filter that you added in save time
    $config = [];
    foreach ($regionLevel2Collection as $item) {
        $config[] = [
            'title'     => $item->getLabel(),
            'label'     => $item->getLabel(),
            'parent_id' => $item->getParent(),
            'value'     => $item->getCode()
        ];
    }
    return $config;
}
```